# Common user for a group

Tags: permissions, centos

I have few folders in /home.

/home/admin

For each new user, I create a folder programatically using PHP

So it would be

/home/user1
/home/user2

Now I need /home/admin user to be able to write to /home/user1 and /home/user2 and to any new folders created.

As of now user1 is added to a group user1 and user1 is the user
user2 is added to a group user2 and the user is user2 and so on.
admin added to a group admin and user is admin

I only need /home/admin to be able to write to /home/user1, /home/user2

I am using centos 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an existing group, such as "users", and define it as primary group of users admin, user1 and user2:

```
sudo usermod -g users admin
sudo usermod -g users user1
sudo usermod -g users user2
```

Then you change the group ownwership of the folders (and all the files under it recursively, which is the -R parameter):

```
sudo chown -R user1:users /home/user1 
sudo chown -R user2:users/home/user2
```

and you make sure that the group "users" is allowed to write to these directories:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /home/user1 /home/user2
```

Then the admin user should be able to write to both directories.

If the group does not exist, add a group using the "groupadd" command.